# Sub folders and files deleted-hosting provider has clue how it happend

Tags: cpanel

All the domain's folder are present. but there is nothing inside the folders! Everything is deleted! I asked the hosting provider and they have no clue! They are blaming me that "we don't delete user files, might be someone from you'r side deleted it" But i never deleted the files and nor does anyone has the login credentials of my account. Please someone help restore my files! What can i do!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a recent backup, there isn't much you can do. Your hosting provider should have a backup solution and keep at least 1-5 days of backup so they can either restore your files or provide you a zip file with your account files. If they are not able to provide any of those, then you can just consider the files lost and that's pretty much it. If that's the case, I suggest to stop using their services and chose a better provider. Also, always have a backup solution in mind... just in case